# Mono on Fedora mscorlib cant install gtk-sharp-2.12.11

Tags: mono, gtk, redhat

When I compile a simple web application on my machine it works without problems.
However when I publish to the server always gives me the following error:
Could not load type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary `2' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version = 4.0.0.0,

In my local machine I have the following directory that does not exist on the server:
  /usr/lib/mono/4.0/

I've tried to install gtk-sharp-2.12.11 but in the end gives the following error:
Requested 'gtk + -2.0> = 2.12.0' but version of GTK + is 2.10.4

Please help me
Thanks
Paulo Santos

Answer (score 0):

The gtk# binding, in its version 2.12, simply depends on gtk+ version 2.12.

You need to upgrade your Fedora if you want to use that version.

However, take in account that the gtk platform is only useful for desktop development, not web development, so I think you're mixing things up.

Try installing the "dmcs" compiler in Fedora. (You may have a very old version of Mono that doesn't include this 4.0-profile compiler, what version of Mono do you have installed?)

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.9 (tarball Fri Aug 24 00:24:34 WEST 2012)
TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       altstack
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  x86
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)

Comment: Thank you for your response
My difficulty is to update the mono to be the same version that I have on my local machine.
If I do not have to update the gtk better. But I am not getting when I try to install always ends with that error.
My server runs:
Linux version 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5 (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)) # 1 SMP Mon Mar 7 2012 4:17:30 ET
My local machine runs:
Linux version 3.5.2-3.fc17.x86_64 (@ mockbuild) (gcc version 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5) (GCC)) # 1 SMP Tue Aug 21 19:06:52 UTC 2012.

Comment: If it always ends up telling you about that error you may be trying to update a "virtual" or "meta" package that links to all mono-related packages, like "mono-complete" in Debian. Don't do that, just install mono runtime and mono compiler packages.